# how to remove "your connection to this site is not secure" from chrome when visiting intranet gitlab-ce

Tags: google-chrome

when i visits the gitlab-ce in intranet using ip address: https:192.168.xxx.xxx:xxxx, the web browser always indicate that **your connection to this site is not secure**. I have addded the ssl cer and key file in the gitlab-ce server and the web browser's trusted root certification authorities. but the indication does not disappear.  here's the snap shot from the chrom browser

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says in the image that the **SSL Certificate is not valid (invalid)**. You need to check the SSL Certificate of the website, whether it's installed perfectly or not.

Whether it is an Intranet connection or a website connection, usually, the web browser only accepts the HTTPS connection with the SSL Certificate is from a valid and legit SSL Certificate Authority (CA) or The Roots of the CA installed in the browser.

Try to **re-install the SSL Certificate** and its root in your browser.

It may fix your issue.

Comment: Here's how i make the certificate file:

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i make the certificate file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
name=192.168.212.30
output_dir=/tmp/ssl
mkdir  -p $output_dir

pushd $(dirname $output_dir) &> /dev/null

echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Create Private Key And Certificate Requeset"
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
sudo openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout $output_dir/$name.key -out $output_dir/$name.csr

echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "RM Private Key Password Phrase"
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
sudo cp -v $output_dir/$name.key $output_dir/$name.original
sudo openssl rsa -in $output_dir/$name.original -out $output_dir/$name.key
sudo rm -v $output_dir/$name.original


echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Create Certificate"
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
test -f "$output_dir/$name.csr" || { echo "could not find file $output_dir/$name.key" && exit 1; }
test -f "$output_dir/$name.key" || { echo "could not find file $output_dir/$name.csr" && exit 1; }
sudo openssl x509 -req -days 1460 -in $output_dir/$name.csr -signkey $output_dir/$name.key -out $output_dir/$name.crt
sudo rm -v $output_dir/$name.csr
sudo chmod 600 $output_dir/*
popd &> /dev/null


echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Update GITLAB-CE SSL"
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
read -p "want to update gitlab?" input
test "$input" == "yes" || return 0
sudo mv -fv /tmp/ssl/*  /etc/gitlab/ssl/
sudo cp /etc/gitlab/ssl/192.168.212.30.crt /home/user/share/
sudo chown -R user:user /home/user/share/*
sudo chmod 666 /home/user/share/*
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

And i do not know why the ssl crt file is not valid for chrome browser